# Getting coordinates of marker in Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm using Google Maps API. And I'm using the code below to get the coordinates of the marker.

```
var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().$a;
var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().ab;
```

Everything is working fine with the app that I built using Google Maps.
But I tested it today and I got problems getting the correct coordinates. Only to discover that the code above is getting undefined. After I console.log(homeMarker.getPosition()) I discovered that this is now the variables that they used for the coordinates.

```
var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().ab;
var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().cb;
```

I won't ask why Google Maps acts this way but you can also include it in your answer. My question is that how do I properly get the coordinates without changing my code everytime google maps changes the variables that they're using.

Answer (score 132, accepted):

```
var lat = homeMarker.getPosition().lat();
var lng = homeMarker.getPosition().lng();
```

See the [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) docs and [google.maps.Marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Marker) `getPosition()`.

Answer (score 8):

One more alternative options

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
    zoom: 1,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(35.137879, -82.836914),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(47.651968, 9.478485),
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Marker dropped: Current Lat: ' + evt.latLng.lat().toFixed(3) + ' Current Lng: ' + evt.latLng.lng().toFixed(3) + '</p>';
});

google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragstart', function (evt) {
    document.getElementById('current').innerHTML = '<p>Currently dragging marker...</p>';
});

map.setCenter(myMarker.position);
myMarker.setMap(map);
```

and html file

```
<body>
    <section>
        <div id='map_canvas'></div>
        <div id="current">Nothing yet...</div>
    </section>
</body>
```

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(myMarker, 'dragend', function (evt) { ..
}); 
This throws exception

Answer (score 5):

Also, you can display current position by "drag" listener and write it to visible or hidden field. You may also need to store zoom. Here's copy&paste from working tool:

```
            function map_init() {
            var lt=48.451778;
            var lg=31.646305;

            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg);
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(lt,lg),
                zoom: 6,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            };

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'),mapOptions);   
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position:myLatlng,
                map:map,
                draggable:true
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(
                marker,
                'drag',
                function() {
                    document.getElementById('lat1').innerHTML = marker.position.lat().toFixed(6);
                    document.getElementById('lng1').innerHTML = marker.position.lng().toFixed(6);
                    document.getElementById('zoom').innerHTML = mapObject.getZoom();

                    // Dynamically show it somewhere if needed
                    $(".x").text(marker.position.lat().toFixed(6));
                    $(".y").text(marker.position.lng().toFixed(6));
                    $(".z").text(map.getZoom());

                }
            );                  
            }
```