# get latitude and longitude of starting and ending point when a marker is dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google maps api. I want to replace the latitude and longitude of previous position of a marker with the lat. and lon. of current position of the marker when it is dragged. For this, I need the previous marker point. How to do this?

P.S. I already know how to get coordinates of a marker, but I want to get the coordinates from which it was dragged.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting coordinates of marker in Google Maps API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11030730/getting-coordinates-of-marker-in-google-maps-api)

Comment: @allicarn I know how to get the coordinate of a marker, but here, I need the coordinates of previous position of a marker when it is dragged. Please read the question first.

Comment: You need to get them before they're dragged and save them in your array (I thought that's what you were doing when you said "Coordinates of all markers are saved in an array")

Comment: There can be many marker points which coordinates are being saved in an array. Whenever a marker is dragged, I want to update this array  with new coordinates. For this, I want the previous coordinates.

Comment: Perhaps showing the code for what you have tried would lend clarity to your question

Comment: Probably simplest to give the markers ids that can be used to uniquely identify them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added a note which clearly specifies what I want to do. The quote was " I already know how to get coordinates of a marker, but I want to get the coordinates of position from which it was dragged." In other words, I need to get the coordinates when dragging is started.

After little extra efforts and search, I got the solution finally. I just need to call dragstart event.

```
   google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragstart', function(event) {
                 console.log(event.latLng);
              });
```

Comment: @allicarn Thanks for the hint. "You need to get them before they're dragged"